# Android Update google map after interval

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have to update google map marker with new location after interval(lets say 10 sec). The values of Latitude and longitude are coming from web service after every 10 seconds.

I used timer and used below code. It works fine but with timer it crashes at camera as indicated below:

```
private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, GoogleMap googleMap) 
{    
    //   return;
    double latitude = Convert.ToDouble((FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtLatitude)).Text);
    double longitude = Convert.ToDouble((FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtLongitude)).Text);
    this.GMap = googleMap;

    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Convert.ToDouble(latitude), Convert.ToDouble(longitude));
    CameraUpdate camera = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(latlng, 15);
    this.GMap.MoveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLng(latlng)); // it crashes here             
}
```

Exception:

```
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Not on the main thread at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
```

Comment: Please add the actual exception to your question.

Comment: I see this exception: Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Not on the main thread
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()

Answer (score 1):

A note from Google regarding `GoogleMap` and thus the [MoveCamera](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#moveCamera(com.google.maps.CameraUpdate)) method that is throwing the exception:

> Note: ...GoogleMap can only be read and modified from the main thread. **Calling GoogleMap methods from another thread will result in an exception**.

Wrap your GoogleMap calls within a `RunOnUiThread` call:

```
        RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            this.GMap.MoveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLng(latlng));            
        });
```

Ref: [RunOnUiThread](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.RunOnUiThread/p/System.Action/)